# Where can I find digital scans of Christian paintings? (examples provided inside)

Tags: stock-images

I need to make a website for a Christian group and they requested some images similar to the ones found on the following website: http://jesuschrist.lds.org/SonOfGod/eng/

I've tried iStockPhoto and there is nothing useful there. Any other ideas where I might be able to get a hold of images like on that site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most images of that style are likely still under copyright and so unavailable unless you can discover a Bible-oriented stock image shop and pay for them.  You might be able to find a few public domain images or freely-licensed images at [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aLife_and_teachings_of_Jesus).